# How to trigger webhook to modify pod after pod finishes scheduling by kube-scheduler

Tags: kubernetes

I have a project that needs to modify the pod to `add a label` after the `pod assigns the scheduling node`

Trigger on pod update using `MutatingWebhookConfiguration`

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: MutatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
name: mutate-webhook-cfg
labels:
 app: mutate-webhook
webhooks:
- name: add-label
 ...
 ...
 rules:
   - operations: [ "UPDATE" ]
     apiGroups: [""]
     apiVersions: ["v1"]
     resources: [""pods"]
```

But how to distinguish that the `update is allocating nodes to pods`? What I think is based on whether the `nodeName` field is empty, but there seems to be no way similar to [Predicate]{}, which can get the pod objects `before and after` the change for comparison. Therefore, it can only reduce unnecessary items according to `nodeName` and `whether it contains the label to be added`.

```golang
if pod.Spec.NodeName != "" && !isContains(pod.Labels, custom-label){
   ...
   ...
}
```

Is there `any other way` to determine whether the current update is to assign nodes to pods, which can `reduce unnecessary webhook calls` or internal processing

I really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Node assignment is done by scheduler. Alsough scheduler need to know all about pod in case resources/tolerations/affinity/etc. could be mutated. So in case webhook could be triggered before scheduling and node asignment only.

I faced that problem when got node with week cpu in cluster. Only way was updating limits on node with `crictl update` of certain container.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it can be solved by listening to `pods/binding` resources. [Reference project](https://github.com/danfromtitan/envars-from-node-labels)